# How to display only date in symfony sfWidgetFormDate but it should pass month and day as default '1'?

Tags: php, date, symfony1, widget, symfony-1.4

I have to display date alone in `sfWidgetFormDate` but I want date and month to be passed in hidden.

I have given as:

```
$this->widgetSchema['fellowship_admission_date'] = new sfWidgetFormFilterDate(array(
  'from_date'  => new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%year%')), 
  'to_date'    => new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%year%')), 
  'with_empty' => false
))
```

It displaying only year but I want to pass month and day in 'from_date' and 'to_date' default as '1' as hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you display the entire date, and hide day and month with jQuery?!
It could be a good and fast solutions...